# how to install libnagsmp.so?

Tags: compilation, fortran, libraries, fortran90

running my FORTRAN code I get what follows

> [ab359@kelpie dm-tebd]$ ./xyz-inf 
>   ./xyz-inf: error while loading shared libraries: libnagsmp.so: cannot open >shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked the library path defined in the Makefile that I use for the compilation

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH := /share/apps/gcc/4.6.2/lib/

and indeed in this folder there is not the libnagsmp library .

So my question is easy: how can I install such library?

Thanks you in advance for the answers,

you'll save my day :)

Comment: You should at least write which operating system are you using. How did you compile your Fortran code? Did you compile it on the same computer?

Comment: Methinks that `libnagsmp` is a library distributed by NAG (http://www.nag.co.uk).  Installation will probably require purchasing a licence.

Comment: It is indeed commercial. If you have a licence (or want one) why not try asking at support@nag.co.uk ?